# Users are not getting Auto Update for new versions of my app

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I deployed a new version of my app to the stores (V7.1 -hybrid) and it is  configure for auto update.

However, users with the old  version of app is not getting update and they are able to login ..

I went to the operation console to disable access but I don't see the old version of the app..

need some help on how to obsolete the the old app

Answer (score 0):

How come do you not see in the operations console your old app?

When you first created your app, it was v1.0 and you deployed its .wlapp file to the console (as well as to the app store the .ipa or .apk file that you've generated).

If you wanted to have in the appstore a v2.0 of your app, you needed to update the app version in the descriptor file to 2.0 and again, publish that wlapp file to the console, as well as to the appstore  the new .ipa or .apk)

Then, in the console you should put v1.0 to Remote Disable and point users to the new version.

If you don't see v1.0 in the console, could it be that you've deleted it?